# How to do Pagination in a Angular 2 html table with out using 3rd party

Tags: angular, typescript

i am having a html table which binding the basic details with image..i need to give pagination on this table. how can i give in angular 2? I dont want to use ng2-pagination like stuffs

Comment: It's hard to explain but I used to do like you want. It's difficult since you need to handle page length, css class chnage on active and all action by yourself. try this [logic](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, bootstrap styled :

**Paginator HTML**

```
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="color: #337ab7;" [disabled]="tableManager.page === 1" (click)="tableManager.page = 1">&laquo;</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="color: #337ab7;" [disabled]="tableManager.page === 1" (click)="tableManager.page = tableManager.page === 1 ? 1 : tableManager.page - 1"><</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="color: #337ab7;">{{tableManager.page}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="color: #337ab7;" [disabled]="tableManager.page >= (tableManager.results.length / tableManager.offset)" (click)="tableManager.page = tableManager.page >= (tableManager.results.length / tableManager.offset) ? tableManager.Math.ceil(tableManager.results.length / tableManager.offset) : tableManager.page + 1">></button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="color: #337ab7;" [disabled]="tableManager.page >= (tableManager.results.length / tableManager.offset)" (click)="tableManager.page = tableManager.Math.ceil(tableManager.results.length / tableManager.offset)">&raquo;</button>
      </div>
```

**The *ngFor row**

```
<tr *ngFor="let m of tableManager.results.slice((tableManager.page - 1) * tableManager.offset, tableManager.page * tableManager.offset)">
```

**The component object tableManager**

```
tableManager = {
  results: [],
  page: 1,
  offset: 10,
  Math: Math
};
```

All you need to do is stock your results in the results property.